# Regtest mode on Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, bitcoin

I'd like to use regtest mode on Ethereum. Does it exist? If so, how can I use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, there is no regression test mode available in ethereum similar to the `--regtest` mode in bitcoin which allows you to operate a single-node private network and to generate any number of blocks instantly.

However, **Yes**, it is possible to run single-node private testnets by using the `--dev` developer mode or any random network id higher than 2 with disabled client discovery. To generate blocks, simply start a single miner thread.

For geth use:

```
geth --dev --nodiscover --maxpeers 0 --mine --minerthreads 1 --verbosity 4
```

For ++eth use:

```
eth --private --no-discovery --peers 0 --mining on --mining-threads 1 --verbosity 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Parity has a development chain mode which sounds like what you are looking for.

https://paritytech.github.io/wiki/Private-development-chain